# Amending D3 circle animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a very simple question. Here is my jsfiddle, where I animate a circle between two nodes using D3 (original code is Mike Bostock's): http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/uxy8d9vs/5/.

How do I stop the circle from returning to node A when it's reached node B? The relevant bit of code is as follows:

```
  var path = d3.select("path#AB"),
  startPoint = pathStartPoint(path);

  marker.attr("r", 7)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + startPoint + ")");

  transition();


  //Get path start point for placing marker
  function pathStartPoint(path) {
    var d = path.attr("d"),
    dsplitted = d.split(" ");
    return dsplitted[1].split(",");
  }

  function transition() {
    marker.transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()));

  }

  function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    return function(i) {
      return function(t) {
        var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";//Move marker
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var l = path.getTotalLength() / 2;
```

Because your path is two arcs, one from A to B, the other from B to A. Traversing the full path it's always going to return to A. Doing half the length of the path it stops at B.

On another point your fiddle ends up crashing chrome on my pc, I think it's to do with calling the transition from itself ('the infinite loop' bit)

Comment: Graham thank you so much, I very much appreciate this. I did not realize there were two arcs. I also did not realize the script crashes after a while. Surely if I stop the circle on B and end the transition then that would stop the long running script?

Comment: yeh, doing it just the once would solve that problem. To keep doing it (if you want to) I'd see how it works here, as this doesn't seem to slow down --> http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997